# Sub-select query changes requires Group By

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the below query with a sub-select expression for `PO_Number`. This sub-select does NOT require it to be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Does **NOT** require a `GROUP BY` for `PO_Number` sub-select expression:

```
SELECT :P_Trigger_ID  KEY            ,         
             
      ,  (SELECT pha.segment1
        FROM   po_headers_all pha
        WHERE  (pha.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id)
          and rownum=1)    PO_Number

      ,   aia.invoice_num
      ,   sum(aid.amount) Freight_Charge

FROM AP_INVOICES_ALL aia, AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL ail
WHERE aia.INVOICE_ID = ail.INVOICE_ID

GROUP BY :P_Trigger_ID , aia.invoice_num
```

Compare that to the below query where I am using an `OR` operator in the sub-select join condition, and for some reason in this case it **does** require me to have this expression in the `GROUP BY`, otherwise I get the `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error.

Requires a `GROUP BY` for `PO_Number` sub-select expression:

```
SELECT :P_Trigger_ID  KEY            ,
    
      ,  (SELECT pha.segment1
        FROM   po_headers_all pha
        WHERE  (pha.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id OR pha.po_header_id = ail.po_header_id )
          and rownum=1)    PO_Number

      ,   aia.invoice_num
      ,   sum(aid.amount) Freight_Charge

FROM AP_INVOICES_ALL aia, AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL ail
WHERE aia.INVOICE_ID = ail.INVOICE_ID

GROUP BY :P_Trigger_ID , aia.invoice_num
```

If I try to run this 2nd query as-is it results in the `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error. Can someone explain why this occurs based on whether I am using the OR operator or not?

Since I can't have an expression listed in the GROUP BY I need a way to get around this...

**EDIT:**

Full query:

```
--BI report query
SELECT :P_Trigger_ID                                    KEY            ,
       gl_flexfields_pkg.Get_description_sql(gcc.chart_of_accounts_id, 1,
       gcc.segment1)                                            Descr,


       (SELECT pha.segment1
        FROM   po_headers_all pha
        WHERE  (pha.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id or pha.po_header_id = ail.po_header_id) 
          and rownum=1)    PO_Number,

       aia.invoice_num
       Invoice_Number,
       psv.segment1
       Vendor_Number,
       psv.vendor_name                                             Vendor_Name,
       sum(aid.amount)
       Freight_Charge,
       (SELECT hr.location_code
        FROM   po_headers_all po,
               hr_locations_all hr
        WHERE  po.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id
               AND po.ship_to_location_id = hr.location_id )
       Facility_Code,
       gcc.segment1 Entity,
       gcc.segment2 Location,
       gcc.segment3                                          Cost_Centre,
       gl_flexfields_pkg.Get_description_sql(gcc.chart_of_accounts_id, 3,
       gcc.segment3)
       Department_Name,
       (SELECT hr.address_line_1
        FROM   po_headers_all po,
               hr_locations_all hr
        WHERE  po.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id
               AND po.ship_to_location_id = hr.location_id  )
       Facility_Address1,
       (SELECT hr.address_line_2
        FROM   po_headers_all po,
               hr_locations_all hr
        WHERE  po.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id
               AND po.ship_to_location_id = hr.location_id )
       Facility_Address2,
       (SELECT hr.town_or_city
        FROM   po_headers_all po,
               hr_locations_all hr
        WHERE  po.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id
               AND po.ship_to_location_id = hr.location_id )
       Facility_City,
       (SELECT hr.region_2
        FROM   po_headers_all po,
               hr_locations_all hr
        WHERE  po.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id
               AND po.ship_to_location_id = hr.location_id)
       Facility_State,
       (SELECT hr.postal_code
        FROM   po_headers_all po,
               hr_locations_all hr
        WHERE  po.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id
               AND po.ship_to_location_id = hr.location_id) Facility_Zip
       ,
       aia.invoice_amount
       Total_Invoice_Amount,
       To_char(aia.invoice_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')                      INVOICE_DATE
, '' BILLING_GROUP
FROM   ap_invoices_all aia,
       ap_invoice_lines_all ail,
       poz_suppliers_v psv,
       ap_invoice_distributions_all aid,
       gl_code_combinations gcc
WHERE  aia.invoice_id = ail.invoice_id
       AND aia.vendor_id = psv.vendor_id
       AND aia.invoice_id = aid.invoice_id
       AND ail.line_number = aid.invoice_line_number
       /*AND ( aia.approval_status = 'APPROVED'
              OR aia.approval_status = 'MANUALLY APPROVED' )*/
       AND aia.WFAPPROVAL_STATUS='WFAPPROVED'
       AND ail.line_type_lookup_code = 'FREIGHT'
       AND aid.dist_code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id
       AND aia.creation_date between (Nvl(To_date(Trunc(:P_Last_Update_Date),
                                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS'), sysdate) - 31) and (Nvl(to_date(substr(:P_Last_Update_Date,1,10)||substr(:P_Last_Update_Date,12,8),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS'), sysdate))    
GROUP  BY :P_Trigger_ID,
gcc.chart_of_accounts_id,
          gcc.segment1,
          gcc.segment2,
          gcc.segment3,
          aia.po_header_id,
          aia.invoice_num,
          psv.segment1,
          psv.vendor_name,
          aia.invoice_amount,
          aia.invoice_date
```

Comment: You can not use prepared statements for column names

Comment: @nbk not sure what exactly you're referring to...

Comment: :P_Trigger_ID is a variable and that can not be eeplace a column name for that you need dynamic SQL

Comment: :P_Trigger_ID is not what is causing this issue. The query still errors with the same error when this variable is commented out.

Comment: My guess is this has to do with how many records are returned.  Normally, you should only have (at most) one record returned in the select.  What you're doing there is probably returning more then one record (with that OR) and that's why it's erroring.

Comment: @QuestionGuyBob the rownum=1 condition in the subquery should be restricting the results to 1 record being returned...

Comment: "Should" and "Is" is two different things.  Test out the theory by pulling out the subquery and running it to see if it actually is.  I don't have a data set to see how your code is identifying rownum.  rownum might be 1 on two different rows based on your join conditioning.

Comment: The first query looks invalid. What is `gcc`? And in your subquery you reference `aia.po_header_id`, which is not in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means you are executing the subquery per source row, but then, where is the final aggregation to get from all your subquery results to a subquery aggregtion per `aia.invoice_num`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner please ignore the gcc alias, I condensed the code quite a bit and just left out the appropriate join to this table.

Comment: Okay. Better edit your request and remove that line then. And what about `aia.po_header_id`, are you grouping by it in your original query or are you invoking an aggregate function on the subquery result? Please fix this in your request, too.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes I am grouping by `aia.po_header_id` in both cases. I edited  the query for clarity.

Comment: Okay, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76376649/edit) your request and get your queries straight, for it makes little sense as is.

Comment: The query should be edited.

Comment: Yep, that's what I am saying. Edit your queries, so they get valid. What is `aid`? You have obfuscated your queries such that it makes no sense to compare them and try to explain Oracle's behavior. I suggest you show the complete original queries.

Comment: I added the full query to the post.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: You group by `aia.po_header_id`, so you can add the subquery result on it to your select list. You don't group by `ail.po_header_id`, though, so once you put it in the subquery, you get an invalid query. There are two ways to go about this: either add the column to the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregate the subquery result (e.g. `MAX( (SELECT pha.segment1 ... and rownum=1) ) AS po_number`.

The longer answer is: Your query looks as if written in the 1980s. Well, maybe it is. In 1992 explicit joins like `INNER JOIN` were introduced, and the use of comma joins is now looked at with disdain. Almost all your subqueries are based on the same join of `po_headers_all` and `hr_locations_all`, which suggests there should be a way to query the tables just once to get the values. There is just one aggregation function used, but you join all the tables and then aggregate all the joined data. If it is possible try to aggregate before joining. I don't know your data and cannot determine from the `GROUP BY` clause, if this is possible here, though.

I have no idea what `:P_Last_Update_Date` may contain by the way. You invoke `TRUNC` on it, so it must be either a number or a date, but then you invoke `TO_DATE` on the result which would require a string. You seem to assume that `:P_Last_Update_Date` is a string containing a date in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS'`, but then you are using substrings in order to remove the center blank and merge this to `'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:Mi:SS'`. This just looks very wrong.

The following query is what I've come up with.

```
WITH base_query AS
(
  SELECT 
    :p_trigger_id AS key,
    aia.po_header_id,
    gl_flexfields_pkg.get_description_sql(gcc.chart_of_accounts_id, 1, gcc.segment1) AS descr,
    MAX((SELECT pha.segment1
         FROM po_headers_all pha
         WHERE (pha.po_header_id = aia.po_header_id OR pha.po_header_id = ail.po_header_id)
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       )) AS po_number,
    aia.invoice_num AS invoice_number,
    psv.segment1 AS vendor_number,
    psv.vendor_name AS vendor_name,
    SUM(aid.amount) AS freight_charge,
    gcc.segment1 AS entity,
    gcc.segment2 AS location,
    gcc.segment3 AS cost_centre,
    gl_flexfields_pkg.get_description_sql(gcc.chart_of_accounts_id, 3, gcc.segment3) AS department_name,
    aia.invoice_amount AS total_invoice_amount,
    TO_CHAR(aia.invoice_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS invoice_date,
    '' AS billing_group
  FROM ap_invoices_all aia
  JOIN ap_invoice_lines_all ail ON ail.invoice_id = aia.invoice_id
  JOIN poz_suppliers_v psv ON psv.vendor_id = aia.vendor_id
  JOIN ap_invoice_distributions_all aid ON aid.invoice_id = aia.invoice_id
                                       AND aid.invoice_line_number = ail.line_number
  JOIN gl_code_combinations gcc ON gcc.code_combination_id = aid.dist_code_combination_id
  WHERE aia.wfapproval_status = 'WFAPPROVED'
  AND aia.creation_date BETWEEN NVL(TO_DATE(:p_last_update_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), SYSDATE) - 31
                            AND NVL(TO_DATE(:p_last_update_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), SYSDATE))    
  /*AND aia.approval_status IN ('APPROVED', 'MANUALLY APPROVED')*/
  AND ail.line_type_lookup_code = 'FREIGHT'
  GROUP BY 
    aia.invoice_amount,
    aia.invoice_date,
    aia.invoice_num,
    aia.po_header_id,
    gcc.chart_of_accounts_id,
    gcc.segment1,
    gcc.segment2,
    gcc.segment3,
    psv.segment1,
    psv.vendor_name
)
SELECT *
FROM base_query
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    hr.location_code AS facility_code,
    hr.address_line_1 AS facility_address1,
    hr.address_line_2 AS facility_address2,
    hr.town_or_city AS facility_city,
    hr.region_2 AS facility_state,
    hr.postal_code AS facility_zip
  FROM po_headers_all po
  JOIN hr_locations_all hr ON po.ship_to_location_id = hr.location_id
  WHERE po.po_header_id = base_query.po_header_id
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) fac;
```